# gspread - does .cell(1,1) perform HTTP request?

Tags: gspread

Once I have performed `sheet = client.open_by_key('GoogleSheetKey').get_worksheet(0)` does `sheet.cell(1,1)` perform another HTTP request to Google API? or is it working off a local object at that point? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `sheet.cell(1, 1)` [performs another HTTP request](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/67f302a6a06cad7f2d32c02f07cae54cf891bae1/gspread/models.py#L396). This is by design: gspread is a "thin" API wrapper and leaves data caching to the end user.

However, if you modifying multiple cell values, consider batching the updates with [`Worksheet.update_cells`](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#gspread.Worksheet.update_cells) method.

Comment: How can I dynamically build `cell_list = [<Cell R12C19 'status1'>, <Cell R12C25 'notes1'>, <Cell R992C19 'status2'>, <Cell R99C25 'notes2'>]`? I am looping through JSON data that contains row number and columns to update are fixed. The only way I've found is `update_cell = sheet.cell(12,19)` then `update_cell.value = 'status1'` then `cell_list.append(update_cell)`. But this is performing HTTP request for every cell. I know where the updates belong and could build the entire `cell_list` without pinging Google.

Comment: At the moment the best you can do is to fetch cells in batch with `Worksheet.range`, to modify values and to batch-update the cell list. To create a Cell instance gspread needs to fetch data from API first. From your example, I can see that cells you're trying to update are not on the same row or column. What I can suggest in this case is to fetch the rectangle of cells containing your target cells with `range()`, build a map of cells with, say, coordinates tuple as a key, select the cells you need to modify and to update only selected cells with `update_cells`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for following up. And thank you @Burnash for creating/supporting such a stellar Python library. As a beginner it is intuitive, well-documented contributions like yours that have made this a rewarding experience.

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful. Thank you.